# Change Spotlight weather forecast from Fahrenheit to degrees

Tags: spotlight, macos

In El Capitan Spotlight, you can search for weather forecast. Is it possible to change from Fahrenheit to Degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure, but if you change Fahrenheit to degrees in the Notification Center add-ons ? (it's the case for Siri on iOS)

[image]

Or perhaps if you change your region :

[image]

Last chance in the Language & Region advanced section with the units parameter :

[image]

[image]